# angularjs: ngModel controller $parser & $formatter still fire after element is removed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the exmple below, I don't understand why angular is still firing the parsers and formatters after the element is removed.  Should I be cleaning up the ngModel controller manually within the directive?  If so, how should I do that?

To see what I'm talking about, check out the plunker, and

1. open a console
2. click the 'remove' button
3. click the 'change model' button
4. notice the formatter still firing

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/R7v5nB8JaQ91WcDGU8BC?p=preview

### JS

```
angular.module('testMod', [])
.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.test = "test";
  $scope.removeElem = function(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    angular.element(elem).remove();
  }
}).directive('testDir',[function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope:true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      console.log('in directive');
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (newValue) {
          console.log('directive parser');
          return newValue;
      });
      ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (newValue) {
          console.log('directive formatter');
          return newValue;
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

### HTML

```
<body ng-controller='testCtrl'>
    <input id='test' test-dir ng-model='test'/>
    <button ng-click="removeElem('test')">remove</button>
    <button ng-click="test = test + 'a'">change model</button>
    <div>{{test}}</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your directive creates its own child scope - that's a good thing.  It owns all the $watches on it, and should clean up after itself when its scope is destroyed.

It is good practice to:

1. Create a child or isolate scope when you set up $watches and plan to destroy the scope later. Since the directive created the scope, it should also be the one to destroy it when necessary and release all its $watches.
2. Detect when the element is being removed and destroy the scope if necessary.  Sometimes this makes sense to do if your $watches are heavy, and you don't want them hanging around when the element that the directive is bound to is removed from the DOM. This may not make sense to do if the removal is temporary - i.e. toggle visibility of an element
3. A directive should never destroy a scope belonging to another. i.e if you inherited the scope from the parent controller then let the parent controller clean up after itself - it is not the job of the child directive to do it.
4. If the directive has set up any $watches, it should listen for the scope $destroy event so that it can unregister them.
5. If the directive has registered any javascript event listeners with on(), it should unregister them with off() when the scope is destroyed.

It is possible to perform clean-up when an element is removed from the DOM by handling the $destroy event on the *jQuery element* itself:

```
// creates a child scope owned by the directive
scope: true,
link: function(scope, element, attr) {

    // set up a click handler
    element.on('click', function() { 
        ...
    });

    // set up a $watch on the child scope. It returns a 
    // function that you can call to unregister the $watch
    var unregister = scope.$watch('test', function() {
         ...
    });

    // when the element is removed from the DOM, 
    // destroy the scope and all its $watches.
     element.on('$destroy', function() {
          // remove the $watch
          unregister();          

          // remove the click handler
          element.off('click');    

          // call $destroy on the child scope
          // so that it can propagate to any children
          scope.$destroy();
     });
}
```

You **should not** have to clean up after ng-model. It will clean up after itself when the $destroy event is propagated to the child scopes.  If all directives cleaned up after themselves, there would be a lot less to worry about when it comes to memory leaks and orphaned $watches.

Here is an updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/APJuA2PUse5rs3kSerHS?p=info) that cleans up its $watches when the element is removed.

Comment: So every directive that creates a child scope, via `scope:true`, should wire up a `$destroy` event to the element, and destroy that scope?

Comment: Yes, it is good practice for directives to clean up after themselves if a directive creates a scope (whether its child scope, or isolated scope). You never know when its going to be destroyed. Its a judgment call to clean up after an element is removed. You might do so for example, if you dynamically create an element and its scope and manually link them together (ng-repeat is an example that does this).

Answer (score -1):

> **As per AngularJS Docs**
>
> We register an event element.on('$destroy', ...). What fires this
>   $destroy event?
>
> There are a few special events that AngularJS emits. When a DOM node
>   that has been compiled with Angular's compiler is destroyed, it emits
>   a $destroy event. Similarly, when an AngularJS scope is destroyed, it
>   broadcasts a $destroy event to listening scopes.
>
> By listening to this event, you can remove event listeners that might
>   cause memory leaks. Listeners registered to scopes and elements are
>   automatically cleaned up when they are destroyed, but if you
>   registered a listener on a service, or registered a listener on a DOM
>   node that isn't being deleted, you'll have to clean it up yourself or
>   you risk introducing a memory leak.
>
> Best Practice: Directives should clean up after themselves. You can
>   use element.on('$destroy', ...) or scope.$on('$destroy', ...) to run a
>   clean-up function when the directive is removed.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

On desstroy, I am guessing you can just "unregister"

```
elem.on('$destroy', function() {
        ctrl.$parsers.shift();
        ctrl.$formatters.shift()
        alert('ok');
      });
```

Comment: Ok, but ngModel is it's own directive, why wouldn't it clean up after itself when the element is destroyed?

Comment: Sure, I could unregister my stuff, and everything might appear to be fine.. but still behind the scenes that ngModel directive is alive and active.. listening for model changes, just not notifying anyone.